# Looping a named range of values through specific sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have a named range of zip codes that I need to cycle through an input cell  in 12 different scenario tabs and spit these values onto an output tab. The code I have now loops through the named range of zips but only for one scenario and only pastes in one cell on the output tab rather than across the needed 24 cells.

```
Sub RunAllZips()

'Take each zip code in the named range ZipCodes and enter into cell C11
'on each of the 12 Scenario tabs and spit out value onto the Output tab.

Dim Scenarios, i


Scenarios = Array("Scenario 1", "Scenario 2", "Scenario 3", "Scenario 4", "Scenario 5", "Scenario 6", _
"Scenario 7", "Scenario 8", "Scenario 9", "Scenario 10", "Scenario 11", "Scenario 12")

For i = LBound(Scenarios) To UBound(Scenarios)
    With Worksheets(Scenarios(i))

        For Each zip In Range("ZipCodes")
            Sheets("Scenario 1").Select
            Range("C12").Value = zip
            Range("Output1").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Output").Select
            Range("C3").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

       Next zip


   End With

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `With`, but don't use the "anchoring" with `Range("zipcodes')`.

Try this:

```
For i = LBound(Scenarios) To UBound(Scenarios)
    With Worksheets(Scenarios(i))
        For Each zip In .Range("ZipCodes")
            Sheets("Scenario 1").Range("C12").Value = zip
            Range("Output1").Copy
            Sheets("Output").Range("C3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Next zip
    End With
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks, but that still did not solve my problem. This still pastes the values in cell C3, I need them to paste across row 3 for scenario 1, paste across row 4 for scenario 2, paste across row 5 for scenario 3, and so on for the 12 scenarios presented on the "Scenario _ " tabs.